# In C++ how to declare an alias for std::array?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, using

In C++/C++11, how do we declare an alias for std::array?

I mean something like this:

```
template<size_t N> using Array = array<int, N>;

int get(Array A, int index) {
    return A[index];
}
```

But this result in compile error: Array is not a type.
What's the correct way? Many thanks.

Comment: You still need a template argument for the size.

Comment: http://ideone.com/42wTSc

Comment: Note that there's already `get` in `std` namespace.

Comment: @jrok Thanks, I'm just using it to simplify the example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your alias is a template, the `get` function needs to be a template, too:

```
template <size_t N> int get(Array<N> const & a, int index)
{
    return a[index];
}
```

You can of course do this more generally for the original `array` template, too:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T & get(std::array<T, N> & a, int n)
{ return a[n]; }
```